# Flutter Plug In

Tags: flutter, plugins

[Dart SDK Screen Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8qzT.jpg)[Flutter Plugin Screen Print Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5649.jpg)Hi I uninstalled the flutter plug in from the android studio by mistake how do I reinstall it again? As the result I cannot run any dart files nor start a new flutter project. I also keep getting and error that dart sdk files not configure. So in short flutter is not running from the android studios. I tried to uninstall android studios but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

> Run Android studio and from plugin setting search 'flutter' and then 'installed', like it's shown on this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLugz.jpg)

Comment: Flutter does appear when i search for it from the Plugins

Comment: make your question clear please, By the way if it does appear why you are not installed it

Answer (score 0):

**Windows** : Android Studio > Settings > Plugins > {search flutter and install}

**Mac** : Android Studio > Preferences > Plugin > {search flutter and install}

[image: windows-flutter-plugin]

Comment: The problem is there is no Flutter on the plugin to install

Comment: Send me the screenshot of the `Plugins` from your `Android Studio`. Check it in `Marketplace`.

Comment: Im struggling to add the picture on the comment

Comment: Just edit your post and include it there.

Comment: I have managed to reinstall it from the Marketplace tab

Comment: Thanks for you Help

Comment: Now I have a new challenge the DART SDK didn't install when i ran the Flutter Installation see screen print attached to the main question. I thought this was going to install together with Flutter. When I checked in the Market place it showed that Dart was installed.

Comment: Install `Flutter` and `Dart` plugin not "iFlutter". `Flutter` plugin by flutter.dev.